# Is there some difference between .is-prime and is-prime() in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

It seems `is-prime` and `.is-prime` treat their arguments differently:

```perl6
> is-prime('11')
True
> '11'.is-prime
No such method 'is-prime' for invocant of type 'Str'
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
> is-prime(2.5)
False
> (2.5).is-prime
No such method 'is-prime' for invocant of type 'Rat'
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

Comment: Not really. [`.is-prime`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/202459ce0b9cf0170339d543529c9415d52ac3d4/src/core/Int.pm#L140-L142) [`is-prime()`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/202459ce0b9cf0170339d543529c9415d52ac3d4/src/core/Int.pm#L449-L456)

Comment: @BradGilbert Of course. But why the difference?

Comment: `say is-prime 5` vs `5.is-prime.say`. In general if there are two choices for how a programming language can be designed, Perl 6 chooses both.

Comment: @BradGilbert But why `'11'.is-prime` and `is-prime('11')` give different result?

Comment: Because someone forgot to make a `Cool` candidate for `.is-prime`. Which just got fixed with https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/f01c50f1a4

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the routine definition from the [Int class](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/202459ce0b9cf0170339d543529c9415d52ac3d4/src/core/Int.pm)

```
proto sub is-prime($) is pure  {*}
multi sub is-prime(Int:D \i) {
    nqp::p6bool(nqp::isprime_I(nqp::decont(i), nqp::unbox_i(100)));
}
multi sub is-prime(\i) {
    i == i.floor
     && nqp::p6bool(nqp::isprime_I(nqp::decont(i.Int), nqp::unbox_i(100)));
}
```

In the second `multi` the `isprime_I` converts its argument with `.Int`. Anything that has that method can then return an integer that might be prime.

This unbalance one of the things I don't like about Perl 6. If we have a routine that can do it this way we should move the method higher up in the class structure.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken (I'm not acquainted with nqp syntax), `isprime_I` has `i.Int` as its argument, not `i.floor`. `i.floor` is only used to check, whether `i` is integer.

Comment: I think this unbalance is historical: from the days where `method` calls where much less optimizable than `sub` calls.    This idea has always been that sub versions should be an interface to methods, so that any class can implemented its own version of the sub and it would just work.  I think we will fix this on the way to 6.d

Comment: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/237019665b makes `is-prime(x)` just call `x.is-prime`